# How to draw on top of any picture a diagonal in Tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to draw an upper diagonal on top of any picture, but I cannot think how you can find the dimensions of the input image for the drawing. 
Input image from [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6k9zs.png). 
Pseudocode

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{test.png}};
    \draw[white,thick] (1,0) -- (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}    
\end{document}
```

Fig. 1 Input, 
Fig. 2 Output, 
Fig. 3 Output from cfr's proposal

[image]
[image]
[image]

TeXLive: 2016
OS: Debian 8.5

Comment: Give the node a name, say `n` as in `\node(n)[...] at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{test.png}};` and then `\draw(n.north east)--(n.south west);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surely the whole point of that question, if I'm remembering correctly, is that you don't need to know the dimensions in order to draw the diagonal. You just change the coordinate system to match whatever those directions happen to be. Of course, this is [overkill just to draw the diagonal](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/340967/how-to-draw-on-top-of-any-picture-a-diagonal-in-tikz/340972#comment836590_340967).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (n) [anchor=south west,inner sep=0] {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}};
  \begin{scope}[x=(n.south east), y=(n.north west)]
    \draw [red] (0,0) -- (1,1);
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: diagnoal without measuring]

## EDIT

In the case of the test image, the image itself contains a white border. Hence, a diagonal drawn from bottom left to top right will protrude beyond the inner picture to include that white border, since that is part of the image itself so far as Ti*k*Z is concerned.

To see this, fill a node behind the picture. Here I've used 2 copies, although I'm not entirely sure why.

[image: demonstrating white border]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,fit}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (n) [anchor=south west,inner sep=0] {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}};
  \begin{scope}[x=(n.south east), y=(n.north west)]
    \draw [red] (0,0) -- (1,1);
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (n) [anchor=south west,inner sep=0] {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{m}};
  \begin{scope}[x=(n.south east), y=(n.north west)]
    \draw [red] (0,0) -- (1,1);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[xshift=1.1\textwidth]
    \node (n1) [anchor=south west,inner sep=0] {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{m}};
    \begin{scope}[x=(n1.south east), y=(n1.north west)]
      \draw [blue] (0,0) -- (1,1);
    \end{scope}
  \end{scope}
  \scoped[on background layer]{\node [fill=gray!25!blue, fit=(n) (n1)] {};}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Masi No it doesn't. The white is part of the image. It has a white border, so that is obviously within the node containing the image.

Comment: @Masi The diagonal does not go over the margins. If you have a look at the image, it includes a white frame.

Comment: @Masi What do you mean by `dynamic`? You can change the width of the line, obviously, either with `thick` or `thin` or whatever or with `line width=<dimension>`.

Comment: @Masi Er, well... that is not really for Ti*k*Z to do, is it? It will depend on your printer and on how the job is handled prior to printing. Some viewers/drivers/printers have options to enhance thin lines. Some happily omit 90% of all lower case serif `t`s from a few thousand pages of print out.

Comment: @cfr Thank you for the explanation! I will leave it then like that and add a note that the line is not a minimum one but set so because of printer limitation.